# Can't create message queue in Linux subsystem on Windows

Tags: c, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to create message queue on linux subsystem in Windows 10.
When I try to create message queue using this function:

```
 queueId = msgget(*key, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0660);
    if (queueId == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EEXIST)
        {
            queueId = msgget(*key, IPC_CREAT | 0660);
            printf("Messege queue already exists, access acquired\n");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Couldn't create message queue. Process ended with error: %d\n", errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Message queue has been created with id: %d\n", queueId);
    }
```

I receive an error number 38 which is ENAMETOOLONG. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Is this on WSL2 or the original WSL?

Comment: @PiRocks original WSL

Comment: What is the name you're using?

Comment: @Shawn name of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1443), WSL does not support SysV message queues. You'll need to switch to WSL2, a Linux instance running in a proper VM, or find a different approach.

Comment: Conversion fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: I am using WSL2 and getting the same issue..